# Windows phone 7x programatically disable cellualr data

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.8

Is it possible to disable data connection from your app? I have seen apis for querying the status of wifi and cellular but cant find a way to turn them off or on?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible and I guess never will be

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. As a general rule with Windows Phone devices, anything that would alter the settings of the device or anything outside of the application is prohibited for security and consistency reasons.